# React Native text input is very slow to update

Tags: android, ios, performance, react-native, performance-testing

I have a chat app for iOS and Android - basic layout with a list of messages and an input field to type and send a message. After a few dozen messages come in typing gets very slow. The list scrolling still works smoothly though.

I checked with the iOS memory tools and it reports that I don't have a memory leak. On Android systrace, it shows that `deliverInputEvent` takes over 300ms.

How to I figure out what makes `deliverInputEvent` take so long?

[image: Android Systrace]

Comment: Perhaps you could share some of the code for what you are doing in TextInput.onChangeText...

Comment: `onInputTextChanged = text => {
    this.setState({ text });
    this.updateUserTagDebounced();
  }`
It's mostly just setting the state. The debounced function is async, but even removing it the problem persists.

Comment: Just verifying, if you comment out the setState line, the problem goes away? setState causes the Component to re-render. So maybe there's a lot of stuff re-rendering that does not need to re-render? Maybe try to add a filter into shouldComponentUpdate()...

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. If I don't have setState then the input field doesn't update since I'm using that to update the text input value. Would re-rendering slow down the deliverInputEvent method though? I would think the slow re-render would show in the Android systrace.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a bug in React Native:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19126

Comment: It seems fixed with the version 0.57.

Comment: Not fixed. Still an open bug: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20119

Answer (score 1):

I have the same app and the same problem. In my case, the TextInput becomes slow when starting typing. I noticed that autocorrect takes some time to suggest words on the keyboard and so I turned it off. Now it works better. I know it's not the best solution, but ... ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯

```
autoCorrect={false}
```